# multiline tooltips show and hide d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a muti-series line chart which is very similar like this https://jsfiddle.net/xn1sLbf4/9/.

Now, I want to change the tooltips showing event. I want to have the tooltips show only when the vertical line is moving on the x-axis ticks instead of showing the tooltips on the entire line. For example, in my jsfiddle, when the vertical line locates at 'Mon 03', the tooltips show. If vertical line is moving between 'Mon 03' and 'Tue 04', tooltips hide. Can anyone give ideas how to accomplish this?
Thanks a lot!!

**UPDATE**

This is the change I made. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xn1sLbf4/10/

I changed the line 192-196 to

```
var mouseRect = mouseG.selectAll('.work-rect')
  .data(newCities[0].values)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "work-rect");  

mouseRect.append('svg:rect')
   .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.date);})
   .attr('width', 5)
   .attr('y', function(d) { return 0;})
   .attr('height',height)   
  .attr('fill', 'none')
```

The tooltips are showing only when the vertical line is on the ticks. But the vertical line also hide... How can I make the vertical line show all the time following the mouse across the chart?

Answer (score 0):

If .style("opacity", "1") in mouseRect.append('svg:rect').on('mouseout', function() { is changed from 0 to 1 the mouse movement can be seen:

Comment: Thanks! I tried this. I changed line 203 to `d3.select(".mouse-line").style("opacity", "1");` But the vertical line just 'jump' from one tick to the next tick, which looks very wired..

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem. You can just remove the following code from CSS file.

`.x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }`

Or 
`x.axis path { display: inline; }`

Comment: I think `.x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }`  just show and hide the x-axis. It cannot make any change on mouseover vertical line. Thanks though!